# SQL query using distinct convert to date format

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Is it possible to convert distinct to dateformat month ?

Column Default Value:

```
datee value = | tuesday May 6, 2014 |  
              | Monday March 6,2014 |  
              | tuesday June 6, 2014|
```

My current SQL query:

```
Select distinct(datee) as dtall from dbalarmnotice.alamnotice order by datee asc;

Output =      | tuesday May 6, 2014 |  
              | Monday March 6,2014 |  
              | tuesday June 6, 2014|


Expected Output =  | May   |  
                   | March |  
                   | June  |
```

Comment: What datatype is the `datee` column?

Comment: That's not what distinct does at all.

Comment: VARCHAR(45) I want to see Distict Months

Comment: Why do people insist on storing dates in varchar columns???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
Select distinct DATENAME(MONTH, datee) as dtall from dbalarmnotice.alamnotice order by datee asc;
```

Comment: It returns me query could not be executed., no database selected.

Comment: Whatever the name of your database is, run "USE {nameofdatabase}"  if it's not clear, substitute {nameofdatabase} with your database name.

Comment: if you're using SQL Management Studio, then from the connection drop down choose the right database first then execute the query.

Comment: or you can paste it in the same query window where you ran your query and it should work and provide you the distinct month names.

Comment: Yeah I know but my first query is working using same database, And if I copy your code It gives me an error.

Comment: okey, so try substituting the "disctinct (datee)" with "distinct DATENAME(MONTH, datee)" in your query.

Comment: Is datee not a datetime column?

Comment: still error, My column data type in mysql query is varchar and its format is the date picker in my program using vb.net. How do I can convert this using SQL query to get Month only.

Comment: datee is a column. Is there any solution? do I need to change the data type? truncate? or anything?. Because it still error when I run but if I use the date(datee) it will run and show data in my sql.

Comment: Date is not a built in method but if you have a function Date('arg') that coverts your datee string to a sql datetime then you can use it. distinct DATENAME(MONTH, date(datee)). It might be a good idea to just save the date as datetime in the database instead of varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what SQL you are using.

You can use the following for MSSQL

```
SELECT distinct datename(mm,datee) as 'dtall' FROM dbalarmnotice.alamnotice order by datee asc;
```

or without distinct (Better option)

```
SELECT datename(mm,datee) AS 'dtall' FROM Dbalarmnotice.alamnotice order by datee asc;
```

I would use an better name than "datee" too.

James

Answer (score 0):

Because in comment you mentioned that you column type is `VARCHAR(45)`, may be will be better to use [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html).
Of course this will work only if name of the month is between first and second `space`-character in the date value

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(datee, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) AS MName
FROM dbalarmnotice.alamnotice
```

Another approach will be convert string to date and then using `MONTHNAME` function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(city, '%W %M %d,%Y')) AS MName
FROM dbalarmnotice.alamnotice
```